# Bash is merging automatic file creation into 1 big file?

Tags: linux, bash

The script I'm using:

```
DISKS=$(df -H | awk '{print $1}' | grep "/dev/" | sed 's/[/]/_/g' | sed 's/^.//' | sed 's/%$//')
IFS="\n\b"
for i in $DISKS; do
  rrdtool create $(echo $i + "_usage.rrd") --start $(date +%s) DS:used:GAUGE:240:U:U RRA:MAX:0.5:1:144 RRA:MAX:0.5:1:1008 RRA:MAX:0.5:1:8640
done;
```

The file on the command line:

```
dev_sda2?dev_sdd1?dev_sdc1?dev_mapper_truecrypt1?dev_mapper_truecrypt2 + _usage.rrd
```

Has anyone experienced this before, what's going on?

Comment: modifying IFS changes the arguments splitting by the shell, here space is not in IFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DISKS=$(df -H | awk '{print $1}' | grep "/dev/" | sed 's/[/]/_/g' | sed 's/^.//' | sed 's/%$//');
while read i; rrdtool ...; done <<<"$DISKS"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `rrdtool` but fixing your filename might help.

```
do rrdtool create $(echo $i + "_usage.rrd")
```

prints out the wrong value, try:

```
do rrdtool create $(echo "$i"_usage.rrd)
```

Hopefully fixing the filename (and removing the '+' symbol and spaces from the filenames) will help clean that up.

Comment: `echo` is not needed to concatenate a variable and a literal string.

Comment: Fair enough @jordanm , I was just helping debug his process.  If you've got a better idea, you should post an answer rather than complain about mine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need command substitution to create the file name:

```
rrdtool create "${i}_usage.rrd" ...
```

should work fine.

The real problem seems to be that `DISKS` is not being split the way you expect. Try

```
DISKS=( $(your-pipeline-here) )
for i in "${DISKS[@]}"; do
  rrdtool create ...
done;
```

This makes `DISKS` an array instead of a white-space separated string, letting you iterate over the array without worrying (as much) about the value of `IFS`.